# Command line node-webkit app

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, command-line-interface, node-webkit

I would like to be able to create a node-webkit (nw.js) application and then be able to start it from the command line with arguments to pass into the application itself. I would like to be able to run the command `release ./project` and have it launch a GUI passing the directory from the CLI argument into node-webkit.

I've been able to compile the app thus far but have no way of opening it from a command line and then passing a `completed` callback back to the command line after it has closed.

How would I go about creating command line interface for a desktop app built using node-webkit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get an array of command line arguments.

```
// Load native UI library.
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var commands = gui.App.argv;
```